# How to load files from two directories using a loop if some characters of filenames match?

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have two directories:
The first one is:

```
dir1 = 'path1/to/files/'
```

The second one is:

```
dir2 = 'path2/to/files/'
```

In `dir1` there are some files stored:

```
filename0001.csv
filename0002.csv
filename0003.csv
```

In `dir2` there are some other files stored:

```
othername0001.csv
othername0002.csv
othername0003.csv
```

What I want to do is to loop over `dir1` and load `filename0001.csv` and after that over `dir2` and load `othername0001.csv` in pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`. And then to use the loop to do this for the other files as well.

Without a loop I would do something like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('path1/to/files/filename0001.csv')

df2 = pd.read_csv('path2/to/files/othername0001.csv')
```

And then proceed by joining them etc. And then doing doing the same operations for the other files.

What I now want to do is to use a loop and load the files from this two directories if their last four characters match to pandas dataframes.

Edit: It is alsways the same numeric portion in the end. And I want to have 3 dataframes, one for each number.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that there are always 4 digits of numeric identification at the end of the file name?  Is it the numeric portion that will always match `'filenamexxxx.csv'` to `'othernamexxxx.csv'`?

Comment: you didn't say how you wanted the result.  Did you want one dataframe for everything?  Or 3 dataframes, one for each number?

Comment: Adding to above would there be the same no. of files in both folder? what if its not the case? May be it will be good to include what do you want to use this as in future to avoid a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It is alsways the same numeric portion. And I want to have 3 dataframes, one for each number. If there is not the same number of files in both folders, i.e. one with the four characters in the end does only exist in one folder, then it should perform nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work using the os module. The os.listdir() method creates iterables of filenames from directories, then the strings are parsed to find matches in id's from the last 4 digits of the filename

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dir1 = 'path1/to/files/'
dir2 = 'path2/to/files/'

# Output list
output = []

# For each file in the first directory
for i in os.listdir(dir1):
    # For each file in the second directory
    for j in os.listdir(dir2):
        # If the last 4 digits of filename match (ignoring file extension)
        if i[-8:-4] == j[-8:-4]:
            # Load CSVs into pandas
            df1 = pd.read_csv(dir1 + i)
            df2 = pd.read_csv(dir2 + j)
            
            output.append(df1.merge(df2))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This seems to work. :-) One question: If I do not have two files which match in the last 4 digits I would like to leave this out and continue with the next one. How should I amend your code?

Comment: This should already do that, it compares the first file in dir1 to all the files in dir2, then the second file in dir1 to all the files in dir2 etc... and then only produces output if there is a match in the IDs, it does nothing if there is no match. I may be misinterpreting your question though.

Comment: No, that is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will throw an error or not, but, I believe it should be something like this

```
import pandas as pd

dir1 = 'path1/to/files/'
dir2 = 'path2/to/files/'

zero_padding=3
df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx in range (0,3):

    df1 = pd.read_csv(f'{dir1}filename{str(idx).zfill(zero_padding)}.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv(f'{dir2}othername{str(idx).zfill(zero_padding)}.csv')
    df = df.append(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
```